# Sql Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Tags: sql, error-handling, varchar

I have search on here and I'm still not to sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to find out what emails don't dupe out in the a_customer table 
where email is in dbo.Remail the query will run for around 20 minutes then this error message will appear.

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value  to data type int.

```
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
  select email from dbo.Remail with (nolock)
  where email in (select cast(count(email) as int) from a_customer
  group by email
  having count(email) < 1 
  )
```

Comment: That query doesn't make any sense. You're selecting the count of e-mails where there's no e-mails and searching the `Remail` table by that count?

Comment: `WHERE email IN (SELECT COUNT()....)`?, that doesn't make any sense

Comment: I assume your email column is not an integer? Your where predicate is searching for rows where the value of email = the count of rows from a_customer. I suspect you don't want to count but instead should be using email. fwiw, are you aware of everything the NOLOCK hint brings to the table? From the looks of your query it may be ok but too many people don't understand all the ramifications of that hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `email` is `varchar`, while the return type of your subquery is `int`. The server tries to convert the outer `email` into `int` and fails.

It looks like you want to select all e-mails that didn't have a "remail" yet, but that's not what your query does. At all.